# Regex for source minification

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

What regex could do the following?

1. Remove all whitespace except when not between two alphanumeric characters
2. When between two alphanumeric characters, replace by
   a single space

Comment: "except when not between" == "between"? Also, what should be replace by a space? A whitespace? Everything between the alphnum? Also, where is your attempt failing?

Comment: Which language/tool are you using?

Comment: My own minification just strips out `\r`, `\n` and `\t`, as these are exclusively used in formatting. I trust myself not to use two spaces :p

Comment: @Robin `alert('hi');\nvar a = function` => `alert('hi');var a=function`.

Comment: @anubhava, PHP, hence the tag ;)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, that sounds like a viable plan too!

Comment: Just be aware that sometimes whitespace *is* meaningful. For example, in a `textarea`, `<pre>` or any element with the CSS `white-space:pre-wrap` (or similar). This means that technically there is no way to automatically detect if a given whitespace is meaningful. I cheat by turning minification off for elements that are known to have meaningful spaces.

Comment: *Sidenote:* If this is primarily for javascripts you might be better off compiling them http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home theres also an API, it would be trivial to make a class that handles the API call and caching even version/changes detection. Running your code through regex on every request would be silly.

Comment: I suggest that this is a problem that is best left to existing code that already has solved the problem, because you're going to get tripped up by a corner case and break your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be replacing

```
(\w )\s*(\w)|\s+
```

With `\1\2`.

This would replace the possible multiple whitespaces between two alphnum by a single one, and erase all the others. As it is it (obviously) doesn't account for spaces inside quotes and all "special cases" though.

See [demo here](http://regex101.com/r/nL8xL0).

Comment: Close enough. Thanks.

Comment: @MajidFouladpour: what's left to answer in your question?

Comment: When whitespace is between one alphanum and one non-alphanum it should be considered remove-able altogether. So, we aim to replace by singe space character *only and only* when there is one alphanumeric character *at both sides*.

Comment: @MajidFouladpour Isn't that what it does? `a =` to `a=`? `\w` is short for `[0-9a-zA-Z_]`, is that the issue?

Comment: My bad. It indeed does. Thanks again. The more I look at it, the more I like it!

Answer (score 0):

To remove the spaces except when surrounded by alpha-numerics:

```
'/(?<![a-zA-z0-9 ]) +| +(?! *[a-zA-z0-9])/'
```

#### [Online Demo 1](http://regex101.com/r/yU4oP3)

And to replace spaces by single space use this regex:

```
'/(?<=[a-zA-z0-9]) +(?=[a-zA-z0-9])/'
```

#### [Online Demo 2](http://regex101.com/r/oM0aQ9)